# Is there a way to add exception for admin when querying with "where" in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

So i have this query that i am filtering with "where" to display only results assigned to certain user, this is code :

```
  public function showAll()
{
    return $this->where('owner_id' , Auth::id())->with([
        'contactType:id,name,class',
        'owner:id,first_name,last_name',
        'CreatedBy:id,first_name,last_name',
        'tags:id,name,color_code',
        'customFields',
        'persons',
        'country'
        // 'email.type',
        // 'phone.type'
    ]);
```

Now I want to add exception to admin user with id(1), so that user with ID 1 will have all the results diplsplayed. I have baseuser with isAdmin and ID of 1

Comment: i can't understand your question properly. i think you want to show all results where id is 1 correct

Comment: Just use a if statement...

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply assign auth ID to a var and the check if it is one?
Something like;

```
public function showAll()
{
    $query = $this->with([
        'contactType:id,name,class',
        'owner:id,first_name,last_name',
        'CreatedBy:id,first_name,last_name',
        'tags:id,name,color_code',
        'customFields',
        'persons',
        'country'
    ]);
    
    $authId = Auth::id();
    if (1 !== $authId) {
        $query->where('owner_id' , $authId);
    }
    
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: hey, yeh iv tried something like that but does not seem to work for some reason, it just displays the same filtered results for admin too

Comment: @VajaMania before you call the the `get()` method what does `$query->toSql()` give you?

Comment: I think isAdmin is not defined but addmin id is 1 that is for sure. I do not exactly get what am i doing wrong

Comment: It filters by assigned id I think i need to change something in IF statement, I will look into it

Comment: Ah, It Worked. I was passing 1 as a string and it was not working because of that. Thank you so much @Rooneyl

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `when()`. You only add the query inside when the condition is true.

```
return $this->when(!$isAdmin, function($query) {
    $query->where('owner_id' , Auth::id());
  })
  ->with([
    'contactType:id,name,class',
    'owner:id,first_name,last_name',
    'CreatedBy:id,first_name,last_name',
    'tags:id,name,color_code',
    'customFields',
    'persons',
    'country'
    // 'email.type',
    // 'phone.type'
  ]);
```

Above, it will only add `where()` to the query when `!$isAdmin` is true i.e. `$isAdmin` is false.